# Tensor network to simulate a specific final entry state

Tags: simulation, tensor-networks

A tensor network can be used to simulate a quantum circuit, especially when we only want the probability of a specific entry (Ex: $|0110\rangle$) but not the full probability of all $2^n$ entries. Can tensor network simulation get the result in polynomial time? Or why does it still take exponential time to get the result?

Besides, is there any recommended paper about this topic?